# I am new to C and having trouble with using modulus

Tags: c, modulus, operation, modulo

On the line that says 'mod = number%iter;', I can replace the modulus with any other operation and it works, but not with modulus. Does anyone know why this is? It just does printf the first two times and then says

```
RUN FAILED (exit value: 1, total time: 1s)
```

There will be more code to come, so the function might me useless right now but it won't be in the future. 
Remember that I'm completely new so please don't over complicate it for my little brain! Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int test(int number) {
    printf("Number = %d\n",number);
    int iter;
    int mod;
    for (iter=0;iter<number;iter+=1) {
        printf("%d ",iter);
        printf("%d ",number);
        mod = number%iter;
        printf("%d\n",mod);
    }
    return 0;
}
int main(){
    printf("C never works\n");
    test(10);
}
```

Comment: What does it mean "it does not work", how does it not work?

Comment: Change `for (iter=0;iter<number;iter+=1) {` to `for (iter=1;iter<number;iter+=1) {` you are dividing by 0 on the first iteration since iter == 0.

Comment: `[help-me]` What environment are you using? Also, please provide the complete output in text form: "print first two times" is not enough information

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the modulus operator gives you the remainder after it divides the left-hand operand by right-hand operand. Your loop starts at iter = 0, and you do:

```
mod = number%iter;
```

Which does division by zero. To use the modulus operator means doing a division, and checking the remainder. On my compiler at least it specifies what the exception is.

```
Unhandled exception at -------- Integer division by zero
```

Division by zero is undefined not only in programming, but in maths too. You can't divide by zero. The comedian Steven Wright said "Black holes are where God divided by zero." So adjust your code accordingly.

Comment: What compiler are You using and which flag?

Comment: @Michi Visual Studio, I don't know if these are all flags /permissive- /GS /TC /GL /W3 /Gy /Zc:wchar_t /Zi /Gm- /O2 /Zc:inline /fp:precise /D "_MBCS" /errorReport:prompt /WX- /Zc:forScope /Gd /Oi /MD /diagnostics:classic 

In GCC (online) it says "Floating point exception" with I believe the line (I think).  In the onlinegdb.com C compiler it says: Arithmetic exception.  in test (number=10) at main.c:12 mod = number % iter; (specifically in debug mode though).